# Does AudioKit provide a high precision timer?

Tags: audiokit

Does AudioKit provide a `high precision timer`? I had a look and found about `AKSheduledAction`, which is based on `Timer` and seems to be the only default option:

https://github.com/AudioKit/Playgrounds/blob/master/iPad/AudioKit.playgroundbook/Contents/Modules/AudioKit.playgroundmodule/Internals/AKScheduledAction.swift

Alternatively, to the usage of `Timer`, I wrote a `scheduler` that runs in the `audio thread` (* it's not see bellow), correct me if wrong. I've tested and it's not very precise, as the resulting time difference varies:

```
func schedule(timeOut: Double, onComplete: @escaping () -> Void) -> Void {
    do {
        let file = try AKAudioFile.silent(samples: Int64(defaultSampleRate * timeOut))
        let audioPlayer = try AKAudioPlayer(file: file)
        audioPlayer >>> self.mainMixer
        audioPlayer.completionHandler = {
            onComplete()
        }
        audioPlayer.play()
    } catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

Output:

```
elapsedTime 4.715054468018934
elapsedTime 4.712334129028022
elapsedTime 4.71259418700356
elapsedTime 4.712263747991528
```

The test was run in the main thread by the following method:

```
func test() {
    let info = ProcessInfo.processInfo
    let begin = info.systemUptime
    self.schedule(timeOut: 4.666667) {
        let elapsedTime = info.systemUptime - begin
        print("elapsedTime \(elapsedTime)")
    }
}
```

I'll have to do a bit more research into what the `.completionHandler` is, but I started by assuming as `AVAudioPlayerNode.scheduleBuffer`:

```
AVAudioPlayerNode.scheduleBuffer(AVAudioPCMBuffer, at: nil, options: .interruptsAtLoop, completionHandler: nil)
```

Looking at the source of `completionHandler`, which is a `AKCallback`, we can see it runs in the main thread ( https://github.com/AudioKit/AudioKit/blob/master/AudioKit/Common/Nodes/Playback/Players/AKAudioPlayer.swift#L692 ):

```
/// Triggered when the player reaches the end of its playing range
fileprivate func internalCompletionHandler() {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        if self.isPlaying {
            self.stop()
            self.completionHandler?()
        }
    }
}
```

So, I'll try to rewrite it to use `AVAudioPlayerNode.scheduleBuffer`, which hopefully will help.

Ref:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/timer
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2169/_index.html

Answer (score 1):

I've completed my research and unfortunately didn't or couldn't find much information about a method providing a precise timer.

The best results I found is based on the following technique that holds the best result so far*, the audioFile has a length of `4.666667`:

```
    let info = ProcessInfo.processInfo
    let begin = info.systemUptime
    self.audioBufferPlayerNode.scheduleBuffer(self.file.pcmBuffer, at: nil, options: .interruptsAtLoop, completionHandler: {
        let elapsedTime = info.systemUptime - begin
        print("elapsedTime \(elapsedTime)")
    })
    self.audioBufferPlayerNode.play()
```

The output:

```
elapsedTime 4.691985241952352
elapsedTime 4.662765832967125
elapsedTime 4.664656096952967
elapsedTime 4.664366245968267
elapsedTime 4.666537321987562
elapsedTime 4.666480115964077
elapsedTime 4.659072204027325
elapsedTime 4.665851002908312
```

Have in mind that you need to compute the initialisation process for `AVAudioPlayerNode` and connect it to the `mixer` ahead of call time, otherwise if you compute all in a single call you get:

```
elapsedTime 4.701177543029189
elapsedTime 4.7050989009439945
elapsedTime 4.702830816968344
elapsedTime 4.695075194002129
elapsedTime 4.708125164033845
elapsedTime 4.700082497904077
elapsedTime 4.695926539017819
elapsedTime 4.711938992026262
```

You may want to look into the `.prepare` method to improve timings (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudioplayernode)

Also, beware that this runs on the thread:

```
AVAudioPlayerNodeImpl.CompletionHandlerQueue
```

Hope this helps somebody else in the future!